# Available translations on CDN for jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, locale, cdn

I am using Jquery.validate in a multilingual project.

All works good, but I have 2 questions (ok, my real question is No. 2):

1) I am loading it from Microsoft CDN: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js and it "seems" to be quite slow compared to the google CDN?

2) To display localized error messages I include:
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_xx.js (where xx is the locale that is beeing used), as indicated here and in all other documentations I found online: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryValidate19.ashx

This works fine for de, fr, es, ja but not for common other locales like nl,pt, etc.
Does anyone know how to get a list of ALL available "message files"? I would just want to load them if they are available, as "trying without success" takes to much time ...

And: if you know another CDN where to get jquery.validate plus the translation files: I will be happy to download from there :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of another CDN that host the localization files for jquery validate.  I ran a request for [each of the localization files](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/localization) to Microsoft CDN:

FOUND

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ar.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_bg.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ca.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_cs.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_da.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_de.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_el.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_es.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_eu.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_fa.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_fi.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_fr.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_he.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_hu.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_it.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ja.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_kk.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_lt.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_lv.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_nl.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_no.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_pl.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ro.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ru.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_si.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_sk.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_sl.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_th.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_tr.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_vi.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/methods_de.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/methods_nl.js

NOT FOUND (404)

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_hr.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ka.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_pt_BR.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_pt_PT.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_sr.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_sv.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_uk.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_zh.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_zh_TW.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/methods_pt.js

Comment: This question is very old, but in case anyone comes around it as I did, the not found ones can be found taking out the underline on the language code. So `messages_pt_BR.js` doesn't work > `messages_ptBR.js` does.

Comment: What about Chinese validations? Can't get this working with the above links even tried removing the underlines.

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_zh.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_zh_TW.js

Comment: If you replace 1.9 with 1.11.1 then those missing files all work.

Answer (score 1):

I fond portugues, brazilian.

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ptpt.js

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/localization/messages_ptbr.js